# What is mechanism that is causing "google" module to be imported in python 2.7

Tags: python

This is python 2.7 on MacOS

Here's my testcase - file called mytest.py:

```
import sys
print sys.modules.keys()
```

I run as `python -s mytest.py`.

output is:
`['google', 'copy_reg', 'sre_compile', '_sre', 'encodings', 'site', '__builtin__', 'sysconfig', '__main__', 'encodings.encodings', 'abc', 'posixpath', '_weakrefset', 'errno', 'google.logging', 'encodings.codecs', 'sre_constants', 're', '_abcoll', 'types', '_codecs', 'encodings.__builtin__', '_warnings', 'genericpath', 'stat', 'zipimport', '_sysconfigdata', 'warnings', 'UserDict', 'encodings.utf_8', 'sys', '_osx_support', 'codecs', 'os.path', '_locale', 'signal', 'traceback', 'linecache', 'posix', 'encodings.aliases', 'exceptions', 'sre_parse', 'os', '_weakref']`

I believe that google is being imported via a .pth file that is processed by the automatically imported site.py, but my understanding is that the -s switch suppresses the automatic site.py import.

What is causing "google" to be imported?

Comment: Good question. I'd be tempted to use syscall-tracing tools (traditionally MacOS has had dtrace, but AIUI it might be hard to start now without disabling some security features) to look at for references. That's not something that happens out-of-the-box on the stock Apple Python install; it doesn't happen on my local Catalina.

Comment: Beware, there's a difference between ***-s*** and ***-S*** (capital) when it comes to *Python* arguments. The behavior that you want can be achieved via **`python -S mytest.py`**. Let me know if it works this way.

Comment: @Alan, I never downvoted this in the first place. Careful about assuming that things that happen near each other in time come from the same person.

Comment: @CristiFati - that's the answer. But sure renders like a lowercase s in the docs in my browser https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html

Comment: To trace where the import is coming from, you might try the `-v` flag to Python, which will make it print out all the imports it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[Python 2.Docs]: Command line and environment - Miscellaneous options](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options) (also visible when typing `python -h` in terminal):

> **-s**
>
> Don’t add the [user site-packages directory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE) to [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path). 
>     *New in version 2.6.* 
>     **See also [PEP 370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370)** - Per user site-packages directory
>
>
> **-S**
>
> Disable the import of the module [site](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#module-site) and the site-dependent manipulations of [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) that it entails.

You passed ***-s*** (lower case), instead of ***-S*** (higher case), so *site.py* was still executed at startup (and also the *.pth* file that imports *google*).

To fix it, pass the proper argument to the interpreter:

```bash
python -S mytest.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You want captial `-S` to exclude the `site.py` module.

Also, if you run Python with verbose mode on, it prints debug info for each import to stderr:

```sh
$ python -S -v -c "pass"
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
import encodings # directory /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings
# /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
...
```

Search through that for the `google` module and the combination of the location and order may give a hint.